# Continuous prediction in Google Prediction API?

Tags: api, prediction, google-prediction

Is there any announcement about when Google will launch continuous prediction. Currently is there any trick to predict stock prices using Google's prediction API?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1):

They [announced](https://groups.google.com/group/prediction-api-announce/browse_thread/thread/9863795ed05376f6) continuous output for v1.1 today, along with the much requested multiple category output:

> training data submitted with only numbers to v1.1 in the leftmost column will be treated as a continuous output problem (unlike v1)
>
> ...
>
> numerical values in the leftmost column of all rows will
> automatically return regression values. if you intend to do classification,
> we recommend encasing those values within double quotes. For example, 5
> indicates a regression value of 5 while "5" indicates a category labeled
> "5."

Comment: I believe economic forecasting of sorts has been suggested on the [prediction-api](https://groups.google.com/group/prediction-api-discuss) discussion group, but if folks have implemented it, they've remained reticent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be written.
The important factor affecting the accuracy of your predictions would be the input parameters that you give.
So, try to vary the input training data between different moving averages or other statistical figures and see what comes close at predicting the action to be taken (Buy/Sell).